# Keeping lead Zero in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, integer, zero

I have a table with a varchar column. I use a select form with values 01, 02, 03, 04 .... 10, 11, 12 etc to store data in this column. My problem is that, when I submit the form, the leading 'Zero' is removed. How can I maintain the leading zero?

**

> NB. I have checked other similar posts but they don't have the
> solution for my issue. I have tried var/char/text and still it's not
> working hence why I posted this question if there's another way to get this done.

**

```
<form method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="dd">
    <option selected="selected">Day</option>
    <option value='01'>01</option>
    <option value='02'>02</option>
    <option value='03'>03</option>
    <option value='04'>04</option>
    <option value='05'>05</option>
    <option value='06'>06</option>
    <option value='07'>07</option>
    <option value='08'>08</option>
    <option value='09'>09</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
    <option value='11'>11</option>
  </select>

<select name="mm">
    <option selected="selected">Month</option>
    <option value='01'>01</option>
    <option value='02'>02</option>
    <option value='03'>03</option>
    <option value='04'>04</option>
    <option value='05'>05</option>
    <option value='06'>06</option>
    <option value='07'>07</option>
    <option value='08'>08</option>
    <option value='09'>09</option>
    <option value='10'>10</option>
    <option value='11'>11</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

MySQL is as follows;

```
    $caption = $_POST['dd'].-$_POST['mm'];
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pages SET caption = '$caption'";
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: _“I have tried var/char/text and still it's not working”_ - that’s because it has nothing to do with your database column type, you are losing the leading zero before that already, because you are doing a _math_ operation in PHP. Math only works with numbers, and numbers don’t have leading zeroes - so PHP graciously “removes” them for you (implicitly converting your string values into actual numbers), before doing that subtraction you are performing there.

Comment: @cbroe actually that's not a subtraction, it's a dash. That's why I used the . (dot) before the dash.

Comment: It still forces the value into a numeric context anyway, with input values `09` and `03`, you’d get `09-3`, and if the second value wasn’t numeric, you’d get a `Warning: A non-numeric value encountered`. If you want to concatenate a _text_ in that place, then you need to write an actual text literal. `$_POST['dd'].'-'.$_POST['mm']` would be the (/a) _correct_ syntax here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `sprintf` to format your value:

```
$caption = sprintf("%02d-%02d", $_POST['dd'], $_POST['mm']);
```

The key here is to work with the data *as strings* and don't do math on it like `-$_POST['mm']` which will treat it as a number. In numbers leading zeros are always omitted because they always exist. 10 is actually something like `0x0000000a` as far as the CPU is concerned.

Comment: Thanxxx! Worked like a charm.

Comment: I would rather suggest the opposite. Treat the data as integers. And format the display as necessary.

Comment: @Strawberry That presumes that there's utility in the numbers and this isn't going to be expanded into something that is intrinsically a string.

Comment: Yes, that seems fair for a set of ordered values from 1 to 11